# Sorting polymorphic classes

Tags: c++, object-oriented, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

I'm learning from "Jumping into C++" by Alex Allain ([sample chapter and TOC](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++book/jumping_into_c++_sample_toc.pdf)) and solved the first problem in Chapter 26 "Inheritance and Polymorphism".

I'm especially concerned about my use of `dynamic_cast`, as that isn't covered yet and I suspect there's a better way.

> Implement a `sort` function that takes a vector of pointers to an interface class, `Comparable`, that defines a method, `compare(Comparable& other)`, and returns 0 if the objects are the same, 1 if the object is greater than `other`, and -1 if the object is less than `other`. Create a class that implements this interface, create several instances, and sort them. If you're looking for some inspiration for what to create-try a `HighScoreElement` class that has a name and a score, and sorts so that the top scores are first, but if two scores are the same, they are sorted next by name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Comparable
{
public:
    virtual ~Comparable() { }
    virtual int compare(const Comparable& other) const = 0;
};

class HighScoreElement : public Comparable
{
public:
    HighScoreElement(string name, int score)
        : _name(name), _score(score)
    {
    }
    string getName() const {
        return _name;
    }
    int getScore() const {
        return _score;
    }
    virtual int compare(const Comparable& other) const {
        const HighScoreElement *other_hse = dynamic_cast<const HighScoreElement*>(&other);
        if (other_hse) {
            int this_score = getScore(),
                other_score = other_hse->getScore();
            if (other_score > this_score) {
                return -1;
            } else if (other_score < this_score) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                string this_name = getName(),
                       other_name = other_hse->getName();
                if (other_name > this_name) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (other_name < this_name) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        // an exception should be thrown here
        return 0;
    }
private:
    string _name;
    int _score;
};

void sortComparableVector(vector<Comparable*>& v) {
    for (int i = 0, e = v.size() - 1; i < e; i++) {
        int sorted_i = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < e + 1; j++) {
            if (v[sorted_i]->compare(*v[j]) < 0) {
                sorted_i = j;
            }
        }
        if (sorted_i != i) {
            Comparable *replacement = v[sorted_i];
            v[sorted_i] = v[i];
            v[i] = replacement;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<Comparable*> v;

    v.push_back(new HighScoreElement("Kate Bush", 10));
    v.push_back(new HighScoreElement("Peter Gabriel", 20));
    v.push_back(new HighScoreElement("Robert Fripp", 5));
    v.push_back(new HighScoreElement("Phil Collins", 25));
    v.push_back(new HighScoreElement("Roger Waters", 25));
    v.push_back(new HighScoreElement("David Gilmour", 15));

    sortComparableVector(v);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        const HighScoreElement *el = dynamic_cast<const HighScoreElement*>(v[i]);
        cout << i << ": " << el->getScore() << '\t' << el->getName() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Avoid `using namespace std`. You just don't know what-all symbols that spews into your global namespace, causing lots of grief when you least suspect it.
2. Your interface should contain protected default-constructor, copy-constructor, and copy-assignment-operator.
3. You should use `=default` when you are explicitly defaulting a special-member-function, so it can stay *trivial*.
4. If you use a `struct`, default-access is `public` instead of `private`, which would allow you to dispense with some access-specifiers.
   Though that *can* be controversial for classes which have non-public members, or generally any feature not supported by C.

```
struct Comparable {
    virtual ~Comparable() = default;
    virtual int compare(const Comparable& other) const = 0;
protected:
    Comparable() = default;
    Comparable(const Comparable&) = default;
    Comparable& operator=(const Comparable&) = default;
};
```

5. `HighScoreElement` should be marked `final`, prohibiting further derivation and thus allowing some optimizations, unless you redesign it for inheritance. Which you actually shouldn't do.
6. Don't needlessly create copies of non-trivial types on call / return, use constant references.
   Only `HighScoreElement::getName` fails that now.
7. Consider marking overrides with `override`, which in contrast to repeating `virtual` actually is meaningful.
8. You should bail out immediately if your `dynamic_cast` fails.
   Consider just changing it to a reference-cast so that's automated.
9. Avoid useless blocks and concomitant further indentation.
   After a `return`, processing leaves the function immediately.

```
int compare(const Comparable& other) const override {
    auto&& x = dynamic_cast<const HighScoreElement&>(other);
    if(getScore() < x.getScore())
        return -1;
    else if(getScore() > x.getScore())
        return 1;
    if(getName() < x.getName())
        return -1;
    else if(getName() > x.getName())
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

10. There's `std::swap` in `<utility>` for swapping two items.
11. Insertion-sort isn't the best algorithm there is, but it will get the job done, as long as the vector isn't too big.
12. You should use a smart-pointer to manage your elements, best-suited is probably `std::unique_ptr` from `<memory>`.
13. You could use list-initialization to initialize your vector instead of adding the elements afterwards one-by-one:

    ```
    vector<Comparable*> v {
        new HighScoreElement("Kate Bush", 10),
        new HighScoreElement("Peter Gabriel", 20),
        ...
    };
    ```
14. `return 0;` is implicit in C++ and C99+ for `main`.

Answer (score 1):

I tackled the book a time ago, skipped this chapter and came back now since this topic is highly/excessive used in the Qt Toolkit - even tho its a while ago.

***Anyhow, you asked for:***

> I'm especially concerned about my use of dynamic_cast, as that isn't
> covered yet and I suspect there's a better way.

*Yes, by declaring the `compare` in the `Comparable class` itself, you made it pure virtual - I guess this wouldn't match the requirement since it really matters if you use it that way.*

1. I also rewrote the sort algorithm from the book working very efficient in here.
2. It is also a good idea to move the whole initialization and random generation into the class itself - probably declared as virtual in the interface class and I red somewhere it would be better to let the class handle the deletion or like recommended using a smart pointer.
   I just did raw pointers with `delete` to test the classes.
3. I also used `std::swap` to swap vector entries, declared variables with `a{};` and `<random>` even tho the book is  intentionally `ante c++11` - this code compiles fine with the `c++17 compiler flag`.
4. To avoid unnecessary errors it is a good habit not to use `using namespace std;` because there are hundreds of questions in `stackoverflow` about it.
   If you are fed up writing `std::cout` or `std::endl` f.e. just declare `using std::cout, std::endl;` instead of the whole namespace - but that's covered in the following chapter a bit. It's not wrong for small examples but not a good habit in projects.
5. I added a random test with random names from a list of 10.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> //std::swap()
#include <random>

using my_engine = std::random_device;


class Comparable
{
private:

public:
    virtual int getNumber() = 0;
    virtual std::string getName() = 0;
//rule of three
    Comparable() = default;
    virtual    Comparable &operator=(const Comparable& other) = default;
    virtual ~Comparable() = default;

    int compare(Comparable& other);
};

class HighScoreElement : public Comparable
{
private:
    std::vector<Comparable*> _p_Vector;
    std::string _player{};
    int _score{};

public:
    std::string getName() override {return _player;}
    int getNumber() override {return _score;}
//rule of three
    virtual HighScoreElement &operator=(const HighScoreElement& other) = default;
    HighScoreElement(std::vector<Comparable*> p_Vector):_p_Vector(p_Vector){}
    HighScoreElement(std::string player, int score): _player(player), _score(score){}
    virtual ~HighScoreElement() = default;

    void setVector(std::vector<Comparable*>& p_Vector){_p_Vector = p_Vector;}
    std::vector<Comparable*>& getVector(){return _p_Vector;}
    void setNewElement(std::string name, int number);
    void getAllElements();

    std::string randomNames();
    int randomNumber(int size);
};

void sort(HighScoreElement &team);
size_t findSmallestRemainingElement(HighScoreElement &team, size_t index);

int main()
{

    std::vector<Comparable*> p_Vector;
    HighScoreElement *team1 = new HighScoreElement(p_Vector);
    int teamplayer{team1->randomNumber(20)};

    for(int i = 0; i < teamplayer; ++i){
    team1->setNewElement(team1->randomNames(), team1->randomNumber(10));
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n######## Random order test: ########" << std::endl;
    team1->getAllElements();
    sort(*team1);
    std::cout << "\n######## Sorted order test: ########" << std::endl;
    team1->getAllElements();

    HighScoreElement *team2 = new HighScoreElement(p_Vector);
    for(int i = 0; i < teamplayer; ++i){
    team2->setNewElement(team2->randomNames(), team2->randomNumber(10));
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n######## Random order test: ########" << std::endl;
    team2->getAllElements();
    sort(*team2);
    std::cout << "\n######## Sorted order test: ########" << std::endl;
    team2->getAllElements();

    delete team1;
    delete team2;

    return 0;
}

void sort(HighScoreElement &team)
{
   std::vector<Comparable*> p_Vector = team.getVector();
   for(size_t i = 0; i < p_Vector.size(); ++i){
       int index = findSmallestRemainingElement(team, i);
       std::swap(p_Vector[i], p_Vector[index]);
       team.setVector(p_Vector);
   }
}
size_t findSmallestRemainingElement(HighScoreElement &team, size_t index)
{
   std::vector<Comparable*> p_Vector = team.getVector();
   int result{};

    size_t index_of_smallest_value = index;
    for(size_t i = index +1; i < p_Vector.size(); ++i){
        result = p_Vector[i]->compare(*p_Vector[index_of_smallest_value]);
        if(result == -1){
            index_of_smallest_value = i;
            team.setVector(p_Vector);
        }
    }
    return index_of_smallest_value;
}

void HighScoreElement::setNewElement(std::string name, int number)
{
    _p_Vector.push_back(new HighScoreElement(name, number));
}

void HighScoreElement::getAllElements()
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < _p_Vector.size(); i++){
        std::cout << _p_Vector[i]->getNumber() << " <-- ";
        std::cout << _p_Vector[i]->getName() << std::endl;
    }
}

std::string HighScoreElement::randomNames()
{
    std::string firstName[10]={"Jenny", "Sarah", "Belinda", "Mary", "Mark", "John", "Jack", "Jeff", "Peter", "Betty"};
    std::string lastName[10]={"Cunningham", "Johnson", "Stuard", "Furgeson", "Meyer", "Brown", "Brackston", "Harrison", "McCartney", "Harrington"};
    std::string name = firstName[randomNumber(9)] + " " + lastName[randomNumber(9)];
    return name;
}

int HighScoreElement::randomNumber(int size)
{
    my_engine engnSize;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distSize(0,size);
    int number = distSize(engnSize);
    return number;
}

int Comparable::compare(Comparable &other)
{
    //    std::cout << this->getNumber() << std::endl;
    //    std::cout << other.getNumber() << std::endl;
    int Number1 = this->getNumber(), Number2 = other.getNumber();
    std::string Name1 = this->getName(), Name2 = other.getName();

    //same as other return 0;1
    if(Number1 == Number2){
        //If same as check name
        if(Name1 == Name2){
            return 0;
        }else if(Name1 > Name2){
            return 1;
        }else if(Name1 < Name2){
            return -1;
        }else{
            return 99;
        }
        //grater than other return 1;
    } else if(Number1 >= Number2){
        return 1;
        //less than other return -1;
    } else if(Number1 <= Number2){
        return -1;
    }else{
        std::cout << "Invalid Comparision" << std::endl;
        return 99;
    }
}
```